# Doctrine 2 - Persist Entity with Joined Table's Foreign Key Opposed to Foreign Entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to persist a TradeEntity. A TradeEntity has a OneToOne relationship with a CurrencyEntity.

```
  /**
    * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Repositories\Currency\CurrencyEntity")
    * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="currency", referencedColumnName="id")
    *
    * @var CurrencyEntity
    */
    protected $currency;
```

I have recieved a CurrencyEntity from another object which I'm trying to insert in this new TradeEntity and persist it to the database but get an exception:

```
Type: Doctrine\ORM\ORMInvalidArgumentException
Message: Expected value of type "Repositories\Currency\CurrencyEntity" 
for association field "Repositories\Trade\TradeEntity#$currency", got "integer" instead.
```

Is there no other way of me persisting TradeEntity without fetching the CurrencyEntity from the database and setting it that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In light of my recent discovery, i felt the need to update this answer.

Reading [about Doctrine's advanced configuration](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html#reference-proxies), i came across `Reference Proxies`.

> The method `EntityManager#getReference($entityName, $identifier)` lets you obtain a reference to an entity for which the identifier is known, without loading that entity from the database.
>
> This is useful, for example, as a performance enhancement, when you want to establish an association to an entity for which you have the identifier. You could simply do this:

```
<?php
// $em instanceof EntityManager, $cart instanceof MyProject\Model\Cart
// $itemId comes from somewhere, probably a request parameter
$item = $em->getReference('MyProject\Model\Item', $itemId);
$cart->addItem($item);
```

---

Old answer:

What you *can* do is (it defeats the purpose of an ORM, but it *is* possible):

```
$conn = $entityManager->getConnection();
$conn->insert(
    'table_name', 
    array(
        'column_name' => 'column_value',
        // define all the columns here 
    )
);
```

See Doctrine's [Data Retrieval And Manipulation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html#insert)

Comment: I appreciate the updated answer. Worked as requested. Thanks!